# File exist but laravel can't find it (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to check if the file exists to delete it when the post is deleted but it's never finding it.

If I change the `Storage::exists()` for `Storage::get()` just to check, I get the **File Not Found Exception** with the path C:/xampp/htdocs/cms/blog/public/images/apple.jpg which I can see the picture if I put in the browser.

Store function on PostController

```
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    if ($file = $request->file('file')) {
        //
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path('images/'), $name);
        $input['path'] = $name;
    }

    $new_post = Post::create($input);
    return redirect(route('post.show', $new_post->id));
}
```

Destroy function on PostController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if (Storage::exists(public_path('images/') . $post->path))
        Storage::delete(public_path('images/') . $post->path);

    $post->delete();

    return redirect(route('posts.index'));
}
```

I also have this on my filesystems.php

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
],
```

I can easily show the image in blade with just `src="{{'/images/' . $post->path}}"`

Comment: try to set this path `public_path('images') => storage_path('app/public/images'),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `unlink`.

```
$image_path = $post->path;
unlink($image_path);
```

The second option is to use the `File` Facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 
$filename = $post->path;
File::delete($filename);
```

Make sure that the image path is correct.

Comment: Thanks the second option helped, because i need to check if exists before delete.

Answer (score 1):

I Had to use the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` sugested by Aless

Fixed destroy funcion on PostController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $imagePath = public_path('images/') . $post->path;

    if (File::isFile($imagePath))
        File::delete($imagePath);

    $post->delete();

    return redirect(route('posts.index'));
}
```